# How to read an xml file from a parent war file?

Tags: java, xml, file, web-applications, accessibility

```
MyProject.war

| --- META-INF/
| --- WEB-INF/
  |--- classes/ (My compiles project classes)
  |   |--- com
  |       |--- package
  |           |--- MyActionClass.class
  |   |--- configuration
  |       |--- config.xml
  |--- lib/
      |--- MyProject.jar
          |--- com
              |--- package
                  |--- MyServiceClass.class
```

I need to read the config.xml from inside MyServiceClass.class.
Tried several combinations like:

```
MyServiceClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/configuration/config.xml");
MyServiceClass.class.getResourceAsStream("config.xml");
MyServiceClass.class.getResourceAsStream("classpath*:/configuration/config.xml");
```

Nothing worked. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.getResourceAsStream()` from your code only works on the classpath.

There is no practical way to get access to `/WEB-INF` or what is inside it directly from a plain old java class, it would be a security hole if you could.

`.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/configuration/config.xml");` should work , but it is a non-optimal solution as this will only be available in scope that exposes that method.

Either put your file on the classpath or put it in where it is available to the webapp via a `URL` ( outside `WEB-INF` )

Comment: is there a way in which I can access this xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("configuration/config.xml");
```